# Show Progress Bar when Endless scroll is loading more data

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Okay so i have implemented Endless Scroll in my app using this [famous android endless scroll library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView). I want to show the progress bar when the app gets to the bottom and loading more data and then hide it when we get data. I'm using Volley to get the data.

**This is my onScroll Listener**

```
scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(manager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {

            loadMore(page);
            ++page;
        }
    };
```

**This is my loadMore function**

```
public void loadMore(int page) {

    String url = url + page;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ArrayList<Deal> deals = new JsonConverter<Deal>().toArrayList(response, Deal.class);
            adapter.addAll(deals);



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bad Network Connection. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopAnim();

        }
    }
    );

    int socketTimeout = 30000; // 30 seconds. You can change it
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);


}
```

So now what i want to do now is display the progress bar when more data is being loaded and hide it when its done loading.

I've tried this https://github.com/pwittchen/InfiniteScroll/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/pwittchen/infinitescroll/app/MainActivity.java but didn't work.

I've also tried this https://gist.github.com/nesquena/a988aac278cff59a9a69
but wasn't getting it.

Comment: What have you tried till now to achieve what you want ?

Comment: i  tried this https://github.com/pwittchen/InfiniteScroll/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/pwittchen/infinitescroll/app/MainActivity.java.

Comment: and this doing something from this https://gist.github.com/nesquena/a988aac278cff59a9a69.. but i wasn't getting the whole thing

Comment: You want to show the progress bar at the end of the endless list right ?

Comment: yes. i want to show it at the end

Comment: @MaxBillionaire I'm an author of the InfiniteScroll library. It's just an exemplary app. In real-life scenario, you need to implement the rest of the code on your own. It will be different in each use case. Library only allows to detect the moment, when user scrolled to the end of the list and get the first visible item position. It won't solve the whole problem, but it can help to create the final solution quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't give you the exact source code right now, but here's how you should do it:

- Add a circular ProgressBar in XML below the RecyclerView.
- Set visibility to GONE
- Everytime you load something, set visibility to VISIBLE until you're done loading.

Hope you can implement the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for code for progress dialog:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TripletLogin.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Write Title here");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: There is a lot of customisation that can be done to it. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: i know how to create progress dialog. but how do i show it in the recycler view when i get to the bottom of the page and more items are being loaded

Comment: Just write `progressDialog.show();` in function `loadMore(int page)` in the first line of function body.

Comment: Dont forget to `progressDialog.dismiss();` when you get in `onResponse` or inside `onErrorResponse`

Answer (score 1):

Inside your onResponse() or onErrorResponse() put progressDialog.dismiss();